# Converting XML to Json using Json.NET contains a '@' prefix for all object's properties

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am writing a small program that converts a generated XML (using the C# [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) to a Json. The converting from XML to Json is done via [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). I have not used Json at all and I am not sure that the generated code is correct. What I am concerned about is that all the **properties** of the exported objects have a **'@' prefix**. Is that normal for a Json code? For example converting this XML:

```
<Icon Name="name1" Path="public/images/name1.png" Size="50x50">
  <IconCategories>
    <string>misc</string>
  </IconCategories>
</Icon>
```

is converted to:

```
{ 
  "Icon": 
  {
    "@Name": "name1",
    "@Path": "public/images/name1.png",
    "@Size": "50x50",
    "IconCategories": 
    { 
      "string": "misc"
    }
  }
}
```

Is the '**@Name**' normal or should it be '**Name**'? Using this online xml to json convert also yields similar results but with instead of the '@' symbol the '-' is used.

Comment: Read the doc: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm  @ prefix is for attributes

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the duplicated question. I was searching for this question but didn't manage to find any solution. In the end I used the proposed Regex.